# C++ - static objects/variables used across a project vs. using pointer/reference arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, static, arguments

I'm writing a simple memory game (the one with the cards you flip) with C++ and SDL, and I'm finding it difficult to decide whether I'd use a class such as this:

```
class Game {
public:
   static StartMenu* sMenu;
   static OptionsMenu* oMenu;
   static GameBoard* board;

   static Card cards[36];
}
```

And then refer to them like this

```
Game::menu->selectedItem = 1;
```

Or should I just construct the project so that I'd instantiate the objects somewhere and then pass them to functions as pointers/references (I'll figure out which ones I should use later)? Like this

```
void processInput(SDL_Event event, StartMenu*&*& menu) {
    ...
    menu->selectedItem = 1;
    ...
}
```

Or is it just a matter of preference? The latter one seems "cleaner" but the former is more flexible...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using:

```
class Game {
public:
   StartMenu* sMenu;
   OptionsMenu* oMenu;
   GameBoard* board;

   Card cards[36];
};
```

Create an instance of `Game` and pass it around.